# Determining a Redshift cluster's AWS region over JDBC

Tags: amazon-redshift

Given a JDBC connection to a Amazon Redshift cluster, is there a query that I can execute to determine which AWS region the Redshift cluster is running in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon Redshift cluster wouldn't know its own region (that's defined 'outside' of the cluster), but the URL of the cluster would give you an answer, eg:

```
jdbc:postgresql://db.cb4ysqlysqlz.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/db
```

That URL is pointing to a cluster in the `us-west-2` region.